# AWS Lambda corrupts image buffer - Serverless Framework

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, discord, discord.js, serverless-framework

I'm having an issue where AWS lambda is corrupting my image buffer when I try and send it to a discord webhook. It works locally with SLS Offline and I can see image in discord channel with no issues, but when I deploy it to AWS I get

[image]

instead of the image itself. Looking around at similar people with this issue I've tried adding to my serverless.yml

```
plugins:
   - serverless-apigw-binary
```

with `apigwBinary` in custom path.

```
apigwBinary:
    types: #list of mime-types
        - 'image/png'
```

I also saw another post about adding `AwsApiGateway` under provider in serverless.yml like so

```
provider:
   AwsApiGateway:
   binaryMediaTypes:
      - 'image/png'
```

When I `console.log('Sending Buffer', buffer);` the buffer to make sure it's actually there in cloudwatch I see

```
Sending Buffer <Buffer fd 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 04 fd 00 00 02.... 162236 more bytes>
```

So the buffer is definitely making it to the lambda, but it gets corrupted when it makes it to discord. But again it does work locally with no issues. So Lambda is corrupting it somehow. I even tried adding a 3 second delay to see if that might fix it as if it was a race condition or something even though I can see buffer in console log, but nope.

```
webhook.send({
        files: [{
            attachment: buffer,
            name: newFileName
        }]
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('FINISHED', res);
    });
}
catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR', e);
}
```

UPDATE:

I also tried uploading the image to S3 to see if the image would be corrupted there and again the file is fine when uploading locally, but not when it's uploaded to S3 from Lambda. Same issue. Image is corrupted. I noticed also that the file size when uploading from SLS offline is a little bigger by like 50 bytes than the lambda version so there is some weird compression going on from cloudfront that could be causing the image corruption.

End to end code of sending the image
from Angular to Lambda to Discord

component

```
     const table = document.getElementById('table');

     const canvas = await html2canvas(table);
     console.log('canvas', canvas);

     const image: any = await getCanvasBlob(canvas);

     this.angularService
         .postImageToDiscord(image)
         .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
         .subscribe((res) => {
             this.isLoading = false;
         });
```

Angular Service

```
    postImageToDiscord(imageData: File) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', imageData, 'file.png');

        const body = { file: imageData };

        const api = environment.baseUrl + '/post-image';

        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', api, formData);

        return this.http.request(req);
    }
```

Serverless function definition

```
functions:
    sendImageToDiscord:
        handler: src/handler.sendImageToDiscord
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /post-image
                  method: post
                  cors: true
```

handler.ts

```
import { parser } from './parser';

export const sendImageToDiscord = async (
    event: any,
    context: Context
): Promise<ProxyResult> => {
    const parsedEvent: any = await parser(event);

    try {
        await postImageTableToDiscord(
            parsedEvent.body.file,
            event.queryStringParameters.assetType
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR HERE', e);
    }
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('file sent successfully')
    };
    return response;
};
```

imported parser file from handler

```
const Busboy = require('busboy');

const getContentType = (event: any) => {
    const contentType = event.headers['content-type'];
    if (!contentType) {
        return event.headers['Content-Type'];
    }
    return contentType;
};

export const parser = (event: any) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const busboy = new Busboy({
            headers: {
                'content-type': getContentType(event)
            }
        });

        let result: any = {
            file: '',
            filename: '',
            contentType: ''
        };

        busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            file.on('data', (data) => {
                result.file = data;
            });

            file.on('end', () => {
                result.filename = filename;
                result.contentType = mimetype;
            });
        });

        busboy.on('field', (fieldname, value) => {
            result[fieldname] = value;
        });

        busboy.on('error', (error: any) => reject(error));
        busboy.on('finish', () => {
            event.body = result;
            resolve(event);
        });

        busboy.write(event.body, event.isBase64Encoded ? 'base64' : 'binary');
        busboy.end();
    });
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: How are you sending the image to the Lambda and how are you reading it from the context? My guess is your either not sending it to the Lambda properly or not interpreting the image data properly from the lambda context.

Comment: It could be due to the encoding or content-type, Make sure, that the buffer is encoded properly along with the correct content-type before sending it to the discord webhook. Otherwise, check whether the buffer is being modified or truncated, or sanitized in any way while the transfer is happening. You can troubleshoot the issue by logging the contents of the buffer before as well as after it is sent to the webhook, see if there are any differences. Also, check if there's any image size limitation to be sent to the Discord webhook. Make sure to have an image buffer within limits.

Comment: I agree with @FakeFootball, can you share how you are sending the image from your server to lambda, and how are you reading it in lambda function.

Comment: I've updated my post to show the process end to end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using busboy. There might be a way to get it working, but it was corrupting the image when parsing the blob to buffer. The way I got it working with a lambda function and serverless framework when deployed was with [aws-multipart-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-multipart-parser). It was super straightforward and painless using this library with aws lambda. No corrupted image issues anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Content-Type header of the HTTP response to 'image/png' ?

```
.then((res) => {
  console.log('FINISHED', res);
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png'
    },
    body: ''
  };
})
```

Comment: That didn't work. It doesn't send the file corrupted or not to discord at all with that.